# NSPredicate/TableView only displays one item, why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data

I'm working on an app where I have two entities, `Post` <-->> `StreamType`. When I create posts I assign `StreamType`:s like this:

```
// streamType == one of my default streamTypes
[post addStreamTypesObject:streamType];
```

My predicate for finding posts that have a certain `StreamType` looks like this:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY streamTypes.type = %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.pageType]];
```

I'm not sure why this happens. Any ideas?

**Edit**

What I basically want is to fetch all `Posts` that have the right `StreamType`. Seemed after all that my fetchrequest only returns 1 item from the database. So probably nothing wrong with my tableview.

**Edit 3**
The problem was with my relationship, should be many-to-many, not one to many. Therefore it only returned one Post item.

Comment: add more code! how/where do you print that log? How do you know that more than one object is returned after the fetch? ecc ecc... Moreover, paste your numberOfRowInSection: and cellForRowAtIndexPath: methods

Comment: I have added some clarifications.

Comment: In such cases it's always good to turn on SQLDebug and have a look at the generated output to see if there's something wrong with the SQL Query.

Comment: how do you fetch the objects to feed the tableview?

Comment: @LombaX I have added some additional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: test if the other code is ok. Simply, remove the predicate (comment the setPredicate line). You should see ALL objects in your tableview.

Right?

Second: check if self.pageType is set correctly. I don't see in your code how you set self.pageType
Test your predicate, add an NSLog like this and check if the result is ok:

```
NSLog(@"ANY streamTypes.type = %d", self.pageType);
```

Third:
As far as I understand, you have this situation:

One Post has only one stream type
One stream type has multiple posts.

The ANY keyword is used in situations where you want, for example, obtain all stream types where a particular condition is satisfied at least one time. for example (assuming you have a "content" instance variable on your post, containing the text of the post)

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY post.content CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"aWord"];
```

In this case, you will obtain all stream types in which there are posts containing "aWord" particular word in the text.

Your case is simpler. I think that you should simply use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"streamTypes.type = %d", self.pageType];
```

Try and let me know

Comment: Thanks. The opposite is currently the case. Each post can have many streamTypes (because it can be used in different streams), but each streamType can only have one post. Writing this sentence might have made the error clear, should it be a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: ??? if each stream type can have only one post, the result is correct. You filter using one stream type, you obtain one post. If, instead, it's many to many (different from the previous situation, many post many stream types) the predicate seems correct. What about the first and second try?

Comment: Hahah, thanks, that was the problem. Always something simple! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same issue using Core Data with Swift and just wanted to add this answer in incase anybody else is having a similar issue.

This was my NSPredicate code:

> let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "routine == %@", self.selectedRoutine)

Routine holds multiple exercise objects which I was trying to return. An exercise can only have one routine but a routine can have many exercises.

Turns out I'd forgotten to select 'To Many' as the relationship type for the exercises relationship in my routine entity using the Data Model inspector. It was set as 'To One'.

[image]